# How to get complete stack dump from profiler in every sample for use in flame graph?

Tags: linux, arm, profiling, valgrind, stack-trace

I really like the idea of the [Flame Graph](http://dtrace.org/blogs/brendan/2011/12/16/flame-graphs/#mysql) for profiling since it will help in eliminating unneeded function calls. There is a catch however in that it requires the profiler to do a complete stack dump each time it collects a sample. This can be accomplished with DTrace or SystemTap quite easily, but I need to be able to do this on an ARM device running ubuntu (which eliminates DTrace). I would also like to do this without recompiling the kernel (which eliminates SystemTap).

Is it possible to get Valgrind/Callgrind or OProfile (or some other profiling tool that can run on an ARM device in Ubuntu) to output something similar to:
`dtrace -n 'profile-1001 /pid == 12345 && arg1/ { @[ustack()] = count(); }`

Comment: Possibilities: *[pstack](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/pstack1.html)*, or *[poor man's profiler](http://poormansprofiler.org/)* that uses gdb to get stack traces.

Comment: pstack looks promising, I would like something a bit more automated than poor man's profiler though.

Comment: Check for the existence of */proc/<pid>/stack*.  This will give the kernel stack for a process.  Something different, but possibly useful.  The `gdb` solution will only trace *user space*.  Ie, you can see where the kernel is spending time on behalf of your process.  You should probably remove the tag *dtrace* and add *linux*.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try Linux perf_events (aka the "perf" command), which is part of the mainline Linux kernel, and usually installed via the linux-tools-common (or similar) package. I often use it to create flame graphs on Linux.

I wrote up some instructions for creating flame graphs with perf on: http://www.brendangregg.com/perf.html#FlameGraphs

Comment: + Just upvoted you 'cause nobody should have low rep :) I believe in wall-time stack samples, though you might know I don't get excited about flame graphs. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

pstack was suggested by Mike Dunlavey which unfortunately segfaults after I apply the ARM patch and run it on an ARM device. Until I have time to take a look at it, I found the following stopgap solution:

http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/4039/print-stack-trace-of-a-core-file-without-needing-to-enter-gdb-interactively

It uses gdb with the following command: `gdb --q --n --ex bt --batch --pid PID`

A bit slow but works.